# Using regex to exclude string

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I've searched high and low and can't seem to find a definitive answer to this.
Basically I'm trying to use regex to show all pages on my site that contain:

**/enquiry/** but that are not immediately followed by **enquiryconfirmation/**

All I can seem to get is regex that excludes single characters.  Also I've noticed that whenever I try to use a ! in GA it throws up an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is probably off-topic (not about programming), but on the other hand regexp is code so here we go.....

Negation via "!" is not supported in the interface - that's why you have to choose between "include" and "exclude" when you set up filters. Basically "exclude" means to negate the whole expression, "whole" being the operative word here.

Therefore I would suggest using two filters, first "include regex /enquiry/" and then "exclude regex /enquiry/enquiryconfirmation/". Since filters are applied in sequence this should do what you want - the first filter will throw out everything that does not have /enquiry/ in it, the second filter will exclude from the remaining data the pages that contain /enquiry/enquiryconfirmation/.

Comment: That makes sense, but is there no other way around it?  The reason being is that I wanted to use this for a funnel I'm creating, which only allows for one filter at a time